# Does Flink guarantee tasks fault-tolerance in all cases?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm seeking a fault-tolerant stream-processing engine. For this reason I test Flink with a simple Job: SocketTextStreamWordCount example that reads words from a text-socket! I ran it on a stand-alone cluster with 3 task manager, and I found the the responsible TaskManager for reading from socket! I killed the TaskManger (kill -9) and did wait to see the result: After about 30 seconds JobManger removed the dead TaskManger! and assigned job as **failed**!

It seems that fault-tolerance guarantee isn't a general thing and depends to the Job! Am I right? Is there any reference that can explain about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fault tolerance in Flink depends on more than restarting a task on another taskmanager when one fails. You also need to have checkpointing enabled, and for end-to-end exactly once guarantees, you need to have sources that support replay and sinks that are either idempotent or transactional.

However, in your case the first place to start might be to configure a restart strategy -- see the [documentation here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/restart_strategies.html).

Several other sections of the Flink documentation are relevant to this topic. A good place to start would be the section on [Streaming Fault Tolerance](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/internals/stream_checkpointing.html). Also relevant are the sections on [Checkpointing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/stream/checkpointing.html), [State Backends](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/ops/state_backends.html), [Fault Tolerance Guarantees](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/connectors/guarantees.html), and [High Availability](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/setup/jobmanager_high_availability.html).

There's a [blog post on the data Artisans website](https://data-artisans.com/robust-stream-processing-flink-walkthrough/) that does a great job of showing off failure recovery via checkpointing. An accompanying [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fstKKxvY23c) and [github repo](https://github.com/dataArtisans/oscon) are available as well.